# Is there a recommend limit on the size of a ClearCase Vobs? If so, why?

Tags: clearcase, vob

I am using CC 8.0 and ClearTeam explorer.

I had read, from some other article a while back, that 30GB was the recommended limit size.

Answer (score 1):

No, I had Vobs up to 100GB, but the actual issue is more about:

- filesystem and disk space management: in big companies, a real-time replicated hard-drive isn't as big (in disk space) as a regular one, and you need to plan your [RAID configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) accordingly (to allow for your vob to be managed by *several* disks)
- backup: if the vob is too big, doing a full backup of too many of those kind of vob can exceed the allocated downtime you want to assign for this operation.

That being said, the official documentation is:

- [VOB host configuration guidelines](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_vobadm_host_guidelines.htm)
- [Estimating VOB size](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_vobsize.htm)

> A VOB database (and, on Windows, the entire VOB storage directory) must fit in a single disk partition.
>   VOB databases tend to grow significantly as development proceeds and projects mature.

Again, no official cap on the maximum size of a Vob, but mainly considerations about the disk which will contain said Vob.